# How to implement integration with a third-party API for example for a CRM system?

Tags: laravel, api

For example, I'm writing my CRM system in Laravel. This CRM system will collect orders from various online stores and marketplaces.

One of the marketplaces provides an API where there is a limit of 21600 requests in 2 hours.

In the CRM system, I want to implement regular requests for each user to marketplace and save new orders to a database. Requests will come from my php (server). If the *regularity of requests is 30 seconds, 1000 users,* then in 2 hours my server will be forced to make 240 thousand requests.

The fact that requests will come with different headers for each user is not that important, right? Will all requests be sent from my server IP address?

In this case it is necessary for each crm system user to provide a proxy? **Please explain how communication with third-party APIs takes place in web applications (for example, CRM), where the number of users can exceed 100 thousand.**

Comment: This question is way to broad to answer. You mention proxies, headers, API designs and request limits.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome! This is something you'll need to discuss with the API vendor. There's really no way to answer such a question here, without just taking guesses. Aside from that, you might have to change your approach to abide by whatever limits they have - and how you do that is really up to you - it's too broad for a question here, and would result in discussion and opinion.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow nazwin, please have a [tour] and learn [ask]. you should spare time to visit on how to provide [mcve] in your question. fyi, laravel have integrated guzzle, please have a look on their [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client) for a start. should you hit an issue when using it, you can open a new question in stackoverflow.

Comment: additional note, in the regard of serving hundreds of thousand users there are many strategies to ensure 24/7 service availability. you could serve the application from multiple server instances and implement [load balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load-balancing+laravel). you should properly write your app in a way that allow load balancing though.